# Dropdown no hide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site > https://farnostlisen.cz/
But when I clicked on menu O Farnosti so dropdown work fine ... but when I clicked on another item in menu, dropdown still visibile on. How can I hide the dropdown after click on another item?

Thanks so much

Comment: `$('.dropdown').hide();` Share the code with us. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
$('.nav li a').click(function(){
  $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
});
```

Comment: I need hide the dropdown menuOFarnosti after click to another item in menu....pozvanky, fotogalerie and etc ...

Comment: @user2579395 check it

Answer (score 0):

Just put bit of jquery code and you are done... see below...

```
$('ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right>li').each(function(){
    $(this).find('a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
    });
});
```